# Why "SignInButton.click()" is not working in below code

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Which element should I take from HTML code below ?

```
signInButton = browser.find_element_by_id('idSIButton9')
signInButton.click()
```

HTML code for Sign in button:

```
<input type="submit" id="idSIButton9" data-bind="
            attr: primaryButtonAttributes,
            externalCss: {
                'button': true,
                'primary': true,
                'win-button': svr.fHideFooter },
            value: primaryButtonText() || str['CT_PWD_STR_SignIn_Button_Next'],
            hasFocus: focusOnPrimaryButton,
            click: primaryButton_onClick,
            enable: isPrimaryButtonEnabled,
            visible: isPrimaryButtonVisible,
            preventTabbing: primaryButtonPreventTabbing" class="button ext-button primary ext-primary" value="Sign in">
```

Comment: what error it threw  ?

Comment: maybe the button is inside the iframe Can you show us More HTML or a Link to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with different **xpath** and *ExplicitWaits*

**Code  :**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Sign in']"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Need to see error first for conclusive answer.